# Too eager infering of ocaml optional function argument

Tags: ocaml

Consider this code:

```
let myFun
  ?(f: ('a -> int) = (fun x -> x))
  (x: 'a)
    : int =
  f x
```

Looks i can't call with another argument other than `int`. When I try to with this code:

```
let usage = myFun ~f:String.length "abcdef"
```

Ocaml emits this error message:

```
Error: This expression has type string -> int
       but an expression was expected of type int -> int
       Type string is not compatible with type int
```

Looks like the inference will think `'a = int` because of the default argument. It is the limitation of the language or is there a way how to write this so it compiles?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue is a limitation due to how optionals argument are implemented.

Essentially, function with optional argument are expanded during the type checking phase using the standard option type. For instance, your function:

```
let f ?(conv=(fun x -> x)) x = f x
```

becomes, more or less,

```
let f opt_conv =
let conv =
  match opt_conv with
  | None -> fun x -> x
  | Some f -> f in
 fun x -> conv x
```

Consequently, since the `opt_conv` has for type `'a->'a` in the `None` branch, f must have for type `?conv:('a->'a) -> 'a -> 'a` .

Looking at the expanded function, the problem comes from the fact that the `Some` branch and `None` should have different type to obtain your desired functionality.

For the sake of type riddles, having different types in different branch of a pattern matching is a sign that GADTs may bring a potential solution: one can define an extended option type as

```
type ('default,'generic) optional =
  | Default: ('default,'default) optional
  | Custom: 'a -> ('default,'a) optional
```

then it is possible to rewrite your function as

```
let f: type a. (int -> int, a -> int) optional -> a -> int =
fun conv x ->
  match conv with
  | Default -> x
  | Custom f -> f x
```

wich leads to the expected behavior:

`f Default "hi"` yields a type error whereas `f (Custom int_of_string) "2"` returns 2.

However, without the optional argument syntactic sugar machinery, this is not really useful.

None that it is perfectly possible to extend OCaml to use the GADT-laded `optional` type. However this can easily lead to atrocious type errors and the corresponding increase of complexity does not make for a very attractive extension.

Comment: I wouldn't say that this is _a limitation_, as if even the implementation will be different, the behavior will be still the same. The type system can't express such complex relations, like "an optional argument is required if a parameter is not `int`". But nevertheless, your explanation is very clear and understandable. Extra credit for the GADT magic :)

Comment: You are right that expressing exactly the condition "an optional argument is required if the type of  a parameter is not right " is not possible; however simply adding Default argument when an optional argument is not present and using type unification to raise an unification error when the type of the corresponding argument is not the default one is perfectly possible. A possible implementation may look like: https://github.com/Octachron/ocaml/blob/optional_arguments_with_default_type/testsuite/tests/typing-misc/typed_optional.ml .

Comment: yeah, I'm not claiming, that this is not possible to infer. But it is not representable in the type system. Basically, this is quite easy representable in a system with the ad hoc polymorphism, and probably would be possible to implement with modular implicits.

Comment: The OPs use case can be represented just fine in the type system: type check the function as if it had a regular argument, to which the default value is passed if the optional argument is not given. The type of `fun x -> x` unifies with `'a -> int` giving `'a = int`, which is exactly what is needed. (This might some difficulties for separate compilation, though.)

Comment: You can also declare `f` to be non-optional and declare another function with id as an already given argument. (though I have to admit it's always cooler with GADT)

Answer (score 5):

The notation `?(f: ('a -> int)` doesn't mean that parameter `f` has type `'a -> int`, it is a type constraint that tells the type inference algorithm, that `f` should be a function that returns a value of type `int`. The `'a` here means just - "I don't care, infer it yourself". It doesn't generalize your type variable. Thus, given your constraint, the compiler infers, that (1) the type of `f` is `int -> int` (because this is the only input that satisfies your default value), (2) the type of `x` is also `int`, as you constrained it yourself (it will be inferred to the same type anyway, because of type of `f`.

Also, the type system here is right, by disallowing anything except `int` as the `x` parameter. Consider the following example:

```
myFun "hello"
```

According to your desire, it should be valid, but what OCaml should do in this case?

Comment: `myFun "hello"` should throw a compile error since the default argument is not compatible. That's what I would expect

Comment: And the error message should say: "Please provide a better argument because the default one doesn't work"?. No, it is not the case, in OCaml, the default argument must be applicable to all cases.

Answer (score 1):

When you write

```
let myFun
  ?(f: ('a -> int) = (fun x -> x))
  (x: 'a)
    : int =
  f x
```

You assert a general type but it's a mistake.

As you can see, when you interpret the function :

```
let myFun ?(f: ('a -> int) = (fun x -> x)) x = f x;;

val myFun : ?f:(int -> int) -> int -> int = <fun>`
```

Let's focus on this : `f: ('a -> int) = (fun x -> x)`

Here, `f` is, by default, a function taking `x` and returning `x` which means that the argument should have the same type as the returned value. You wrote that `f` is of type `'a -> int` then the type of the returned value is `int` thus the type of the parameter is `int` too (and not `'a`).

You can simply write : `f: ('a -> 'a) = (fun x -> x)` and everything will work fine.

```
let myFun ?(f: ('a -> 'a) = (fun x -> x)) x = f x;;

val myFun : ?f:('a -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'a = <fun>
```

---

Update

If you want your function to always return an `int`, you have to change the default function. For example, you can write :

```
let myFun ?(f: ('a -> int) = (fun _ -> 0)) x = f x;;

val myFun : ?f:('a -> int) -> 'a -> 'a = <fun>
```

Comment: yes, but I'd like to have a situation when the `f` argument has more general type than it's default value

Answer (score 0):

Type inference happen at "let" level, so this kind of polymorphism is impossible.

The only way is to go is without optional argument

```
let myFun f x : int = f x;;

myFun id 1;;
myFun int_of_string "2";;
myFun String.length "abc";;
```

Where `id` is `fun x -> x`